# "Marked as duplicate" box should include a link to the dupe target

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, new-users

When I close a question, it gets a box appended that says

> **marked** as duplicate by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) some mins ago
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [edit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/*/edit) to explain how it is different or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

New users regularly get confused by this message. It states that there already is an answer to their question somewhere, but doesn't point to it.

(IIRC, they also get a special notification, whose text I don't know).

I've had them ask in the comments for the link to the answer a few times, the latest example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857816/percentages-not-adding-up-to-100?noredirect=1#comment67003941_39857816):

> Why is this marked as exact duplicate? Please provide a link to the question that is exact, I would be glad to follow it. – *theOP* some mins ago

Apparently the first box right under the question title isn't prominent enough :-) My suggestion would be to add a link in the second box as well:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/id/the-target-question). If those answers do not fully address your question, please [edit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/*/edit) to explain how it is different or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: How should it handle multiple dupe targets?

Comment: @NathanOliver Dunno, maybe something like "*an answer [here](http://.stackoverflow.com/), [there](http://.stackoverflow.com/) or [elsewhere](http://.stackoverflow.com/)*"? Or maybe the section "*has an answer*" should be made the link, referencing the anchor of the upper box with the list of targets?

Comment: Strongly related MSE feature (preview duplicate answer): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198961/178816

Comment: This one, for a recent example:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Comment: By which I mean; when I read that question I skipped straight past the 'This question already has an answer' to the code sections.   For your readers, to keep to least surprises and least effort (especially at 03:00) - include a link to the original question at every point you assert that it is a duplicate.