# Vote to close as a duplicate of an answer

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

MANY times questions that seem not to be exact duplicates are often answered the same way. I've seen conversations like this as long as dupe closures were a thing

> [image]

I'd wager a decent percentage of folks who get their questions closed as duplicate don't bother considering the answers if, when they click on the duplicate link in the header, they only read the presented question and determine it's not 100% the same as theirs. Probably leads to them thinking SO isn't that nice.

I think there was a blog post or something about that, I've been a bit out of the loop. Send me a link if you know what I'm talking about?

Anyhow, perhaps in addition to closing as dupe of another question, allow users to close questions as duplicates of an **answer** as well. This may give a better closure experience for the OP. Let me explain.

When closing a question as a duplicate of another, instead of pasting a link to the question into the closure form, paste a link to an answer. The system still closes the question as a dupe of another, but uses a different header format.

> [image]

Okay, the wording sucks, but I'm not here to impress you with my englishing.

Another design option:

> [image]

The link would not direct the user to the question, but would take the user directly to the answer. The OP is guided to consider the *answer's suitability rather than the question's similarity*.

Cons:

The current duplicate search UI only finds questions, and it would probably not be feasible or make much sense to support searching for answers.

---

<edit>
One possible solution to this con is to include the accepted and/or highest voted answer to that question as bullet points below the question. The user then has the option of selecting the question or one of the listed answers as the duplicate target. Yeah. Nice.
</edit>

---

But this feature wouldn't really be useful anyhow unless the person using it *already knows the answer they want to point the user to*. Or, if they don't have the link to the answer and find the question in the result set, they can open a candidate in a new tab to snag the share link.

Another con is the editing experience. Perhaps split the edit into questions in one list and answers in another?

---

It's not a big fix, but another tool in the box, and might help folks stop with the freakouts about dupe closure.

Comment: eh, i see where you're going with this, but... like, i dunno, seems like this would drastically open up the number of questions that can be closed as duplicates, and i'm not convinced that that is a good thing.

Comment: I'm skeptical of this. As hvd said in the exchange you screen shotted, he (a power user), didn't even notice the answer applied due to the amount of unrelated information in it. I think the site would be better off with both questions, as the 2nd one might have a more localized answer, making it faster to read and easier for people inexperienced with the topic to understand.

Comment: @KevinB:  Wait.  You mean to tell me you want to see *fewer* questions closed as duplicates??  It isn't like the guidance on what to close as a dupe is changing here, but what's being displayed *is*.

Comment: No, i mean, i can see it being abused. but a lot of things can be abused, so that might be a moot point. i'm just not convinced.

Comment: Feel encouraged to elaborate on the potential cases for abuse in an answer.  I don't disagree that they exist either, but I feel like there's more benefit than detriment here.

Comment: That rude lizard fellow could have linked to the relevant answer in his comment. That's what *I* would have done.

Comment: I will post on every question on the site "Yes" and "No". I would like how much time that would take for the community to close everything as duplicate.

Comment: @Braiam:  You can't close questions as duplicates of deleted posts, so

Comment: I think you are aiming too low.  If closing a question as a dup is *really* considered that horrible then just don't close it.  There is no point to it anyway, all that anybody needs is the link to the duplicate.  If somebody want to add an answer anyway then that is a pretty harmless waste of time and not at all different from the question getting closed too late.

Comment: related: [“Marked as duplicate” box should include a link to the dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335738/839601) - which in turn has comments referring MSE cross-site dupe: [Show duplicate suggestions as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166844/165773)

Comment: I don't like the time this suggestion comes up.

Answer (score 33):

I like the philosophy behind this.  It reinforces why dupe closures are okay if they're not 100% the same question, and it takes the sting out of the OP thinking that we're maligning or offending them because the wording on the question is ever so slightly different.

If there was a criticism to offer, it'd be the case that the link doesn't make mention of the usefulness of the answer.  An upvote score there (with some variance; only show it if it comes within the top 5 answers or something) would be useful so that the OP at least *understands* we're not trying to BS them here.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXZzq.png

Comment: @Will:  Precisely.  Something like that, at least.

Comment: This is especially useful on Meta SE, where we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [meta-tag:faq] if the question is answered in a small part of the FAQ.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think a question should be closed just because an answer to another question solves it. Consider this scenario:

We have the question X and the answer A, which solves. Then someone asks question Y, which can also be solved by answer A. So it's closed as a dupe. Now I come up with answer B, which solves Y (maybe even better than X does), but not A. So where should I post it? Clearly it shouldn't be an answer to X because it doesn't solve X. But Y is closed, so I can't post it there either. Sure the question already has an answer, but the existence of one correct answer does not mean that there's no room for other answers anymore. If it did, questions would be auto-closed once there's an accepted answer.

In fact, that's pretty much the effect that closing as a duplicate of an answer would have: The community (instead of the OP) would accept an answer and then prevent any other answers from being posted. I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: In your mind, what's preferable:  a hundred similar answers posted by a hundred different people, or one canonical answer posted by one person?  Which is easier to maintain?  The point of dupe closure is to make information easier to find; your scenario flies in the face of this.  Sure, there are slight variations on solutions out there, but having one place to put them would allow us to select the most appropriate duplicate *without* spreading it across the winds.  For context, look at the [NPE dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1079354) for Java.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not talking about slight variations. I'm talking about a completely different answer that wouldn't apply to the other question. I understand the point of a canonical answer, but different questions can have different answers even if some of the possible answers overlap. I'm not really sure how the NPE example applies here - that is, I don't see scenario where a question that isn't about an NPE could be answered by one of the answers to the NPE question.

Comment: The guidance on what and *when* to close a duplicate hasn't changed with this proposal.  We're getting an additional target of what answer specifically applies with a dupe-worthy question.  Closing questions as dupes when they're not dupes at all is still an abuse of the system and would still be subject to the same rules as any other dupe closure.

Comment: See [my question on the mother meta about the existence of question-question-answer tuples like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q) — especially if you have more specific examples to add!

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a good idea.

However, there will need to be some changes to the "close as duplicate" dialog as well. (With the workflow you've proposed, I'd end up closing against certain answers by accident. Others might not be aware that the feature changed.) I'm imagining something like this:

> [image]

Note how:

- The button to close as a duplicate is disabled because no post is selected. In the image I opted for a more extreme option of needing to select an answer but this would also work if we allow selecting the question as the place where the dupe target leads to (which would just be closure as normal).

Comment: I don't think Will is suggesting that the new dupe-close option *replace* the old way.

Comment: It's absolutely **not** to replace the old way. It's to add the ability to detect answer links and use a different UI for displaying duplicate closure.

Comment: @Will Pasting answer links into the box currently lets you close against its question. I frequently do this, and I'd only end up closing by accident against an answer if the system changed.

Comment: How do you get the answer link? What's the process? I'd like to understand how that would work...

Comment: @Will I'm not sure what you're asking, since you clearly know how to get an answer link (i.e. the share button under the post). In the mechanism I'm suggesting, you have to explicitly select an answer or the question (in my example it's like accepting an answer, by checking the checkmark next to the question or answer).

Comment: I can't understand how you "frequently" find yourself with an answer link to a question that you want to use as a close target. If I were to describe the process of how I close a question, it's typically "1) vote to close as duplicate 2) select one of the presented duplicate targets if it's the question I want to be the dupe target, or if I can't find it, 3) search for the question on SO or in a search engine, open candidates, locate the correct question and then get the link from the URL bar." Could you describe your process and how you end up with an answer URL? I'm trying to understand...

Comment: Oh, side note, it would be pretty easy to have two closure buttons when the website identifies you using an answer link in the close dialog--one for closing as dupe of the question, and one for closing as dupe to the answer, possibly with additional guidance on it's use.

Comment: @Will Whenever I'm looking for duplicates (always done via search, never the VtC dialog), I read the answers to see if they're any good (if not, I usually look for a different question). So the closest share link is usually an answer for me. And I always use a share link (not the URL). You don't have to tell me I'm weird, I already know it. :P

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You got me all confusipated. Good on ya for verifying the answers work for the dupe.

Answer (score 6):

I am familiar with this problem. It's not uncommon for me to leave a comment like "Look at the 3rd answer in that duplicate" after a closure. There is no doubt that there is room for improvement here, **but I don't think closing questions as a duplicate of a specific answer is the solution**.

Why? For one thing, it (sort of) bypasses voting. By linking the asker to a specific answer, you acknowledge that this specific answer is different from the others. People reading the answer have to assume that the other answers don't address the same issue and consequently they have no reason to even read them. They can't up- *or* downvote the other answers because those answers answer a different question. If a new, better, answer is posted, people won't read it and it'll go unnoticed. You have consequently marked this specific answer as *"the one true solution"*. You're putting competing answers at a disadvantage.

Secondly, I think it's a band-aid solution that doesn't address the *real* problem: **There shouldn't be such an odd-one-out answer in the first place**. The mere existence of such an answer is (in most cases) a problem. To give an example: I recently came across an answer that explains how to terminate a process on Windows in a question that was originally about linux (as indicated by the `linux` tag). And it had a score of +15! But why is there a Windows-only answer in a linux question, and why is it upvoted? This is a situation that shouldn't be accepted, much less reinforced by closing questions as a duplicate of this particular answer.

So I think we need to tackle this problem on a different level. If the problem is that two questions *look* different even though they have the same answer, try editing one of the questions to make it more obvious that they're asking the same thing. If it helps, consider rewriting the question to make it less specific. The less specific the problem statement is, the easier it is to understand that the question really *is* a duplicate. If it's a linux question that has Windows-specific answers, turn it into a cross-platform question. Do everything you can to make that one answer stand out as little as possible, and then close the question as a duplicate of another *question*, not an *answer*.

Comment: re paragraphs, first index being 0: 1) if you don't want to highlight a single answer simply vote as a dupe of the question instead. 2) That's not a problem. 3) That's a fine solution, of course. One that can be done now. But that's not what the FR is attempting to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I like this idea a lot. It seems to address one of the very common criticisms from places/people that are on the "SO isn't beginner friendly" train.

(Seriously, "my question was closed as a duplicate of something only vaguely related" seems to be both the most common and hardest to refute criticism of SO, irrespective of its true validity).

Linking the specific answer makes it both more likely for the user to be satisfied, and makes it easier for the user to address why their question is different, if it actually is.